# Source for saying a bracha rishona after eating?

Tags: halacha, blessing, eating

I've heard that there are those who hold that saying a bracha rishona (ie the bracha usually said before eating) after you have eaten a food is effectual.  Where might I find a source that says that?

(For example, you ate an apple and as just as you swallowed the last bite you remembered that you did not say borei pri ha-etz before you started eating. You then say borei pri ha-etz, even though you are done eating.)

Answer (score 3):

See Shulchan Arukh OC 172 for such an opinion (that if you drink and remember before swallowing that you didn't say a Bracha you can swallow and say a Bracha after swallowing) quoted in the Rama.

(I note it is a somewhat controversial position, so CYLOR for a final ruling.)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, your source applies only in a case when he remembers the beracha while he stills has the food in the mouth.

Comment: @Emilios1995 I see no such limitation in the question. The Bracha is said very much after swallowing.

Comment: look at the final paragraph of the question:  " and as just as you swallowed the last bite you remembered that you did not say borei pri ha-etz "

Comment: @Emilios1995 That's a pretty ambiguous terminology in my opinion. Where exactly is the bolus at the moment he remembers? Plus I believe this is the closest he will get to such an opinion if it is being held Lemaaseh and hence probably what was being referenced by the people he heard about it from.

Comment: Yes. The Mishnah Berurah on 172 says this seems to be the prevalent opinion.  But it is not clear to me which opinion he is referring to.

Comment: @doubleAA I agree. but remember we have to answer what the user is asking, and if you don't, you should specify it. He made himself very clear with that example at the end.

Comment: @Emilios1995 I completely disagree that he made himself clear that this case is excluded, as I told you above.

Comment: @Emilios1995 I went ahead and clarified the specific case under discussion there.

Comment: @YehudaW I'm not sure what is confusing you about the MB. He seems to reject this opinion and prefer the opinion of the Shulchan Arukh (and R Chananel) that no Bracha is said in this case.

Comment: Because there is more to drink and this was only a sip or bite of what he intended to consume?

Comment: @Dude No, this is where there is no other food, see beiur halacha

Answer (score 2):

It's in berachot 51, acording to Rabbina you can bless even if you remebered you didn't after you are done eating.
The Raabad holds this opinion.
 Here is an essay about it:
http://ybm.org.il/hebrew/LessonArticle.aspx?item=1891

Comment: Just for the record this opinion of the Raavad is in the extreme minority. It is not the opinion I reference in my answer.